# How to remove an element from gradle task outputs?

Tags: gradle

is it possible to exclude an element from the output files of a Task in order to not consider it for the up-to-date check? In my case I have a copy task that automatically set the destination directory in outputs variable, but I'd like to remove it and set only some of the copied files.

Or, as alternative, is it possible to overwrite the entire outputs variable?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Do you need just to force task execution? What's the point of task outputs modification?

Comment: I'd like to live the possibility to "hijack" some files, without re-run the task if these files (which are part of the output files of the task). In order to do this I'd like to modify the outputs.files properties removing some entry.

Answer (score 2):

Incremental tasks create snapshots from input and output files of a task. If these snapshots are the same for two task executions (based on the hash code of file content), then Gradle assumes that task is up-to-date.

You are not able to remove some files from output and expect Gradle to forget about them, simply because the hash codes will be different.

There is an option that allows you to manually define the logic of up-to-date checks.

You should use a method `upToDateWhen(Closure upToDateClosure)` in [TaskOutputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html) class.

```
task myTask {
   outputs.dir files('/home/user/test')
   outputs.upToDateWhen {
      // your logic here
      return true; // always up-to-date
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but I was like to left it as last resource. I would like to use the upToDate logic already provided by gradle since I only need to modify the list of the file inclued in the snapshots. What if I redefine the outputs.files list? Maybe using setFrom method: in this way I can reset the output list and add only the files I need to check. Could it be possible?

Comment: @Mikyjpeg I think changing outputs value (even if it was possible) won't help because hash codes would be different

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: I mean the outputs.files property of the task. If I remove a file from this list it will be not part of the snapshot used for the up-to-date check, so it hash code should not be used.

Comment: @Mikyjpeg imagine you have two files in task outputs, they are in snapshot and their hash is 141455. Now you remove one file from outputs and call gradle task. Snapshot is made from this single file and its hash code is 4234. Since hash is different, task is not up-to-date.

Comment: If I remove the file from the configuration list (not after the run) the file it is no more check for up-to-date (see my answer below, I just tried it).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
task reduceZip(type: Copy) {

   outputs.files.setFrom(file("C:/temp/unzip/test.properties"))
   outputs.file(file("C:/temp/unzip/test.txt"))

   from zipTree("C:/temp/temp.zip")
   into "C:/temp/unzip"
}
```

Outputs.files list could be modified only register new elements, not removing (for what I know). So I need to reset the list and then eventually add other files. The `outputs.files.setFrom` method reset the outputs.files list so it is possible add other file. In the example above I reduce the up-to-date check only to the test.properties and test.txt files.