# How do I remove/overwrite the outputs from a gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have dynamic defined a task in build.gradle, that inherits from another task.
In the following I'm using kotlin-DSL, but I'm happy with solutions for groovy dsl as well.

```
task.register<GenerateTask>("generateCode") {
    // stuff
    outputDir.set("$rootDir")
}
```

As you can see I had to define the output as rootDir.
However I'm setting options to only create part of the output.
All the generated code is in a specificPackage meaning it will all end up in:

```
$rootDir/src/main/my/generated/package/name
$rootDir/src/test/my/generated/package/name
```

However due to outputDir being set it assumes the whole rootdir is an output and warns me accordingly.
Now I would like to tell gradle, that this task only produces those two packages.

I tried overwriting `outputs` but it is readonly.
I tried overwriting `outputs.files` but it is readonly.
I tried using `outputs.files.setFrom()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314409/how-to-remove-an-element-from-gradle-task-outputs), but this seems no longer to be valid.

Is there a way to set outputDir, but not add the value it to outputs or a way to clear the outputs list?

Comment: What type is `outputDir` and can you change it or the annotation on it? (I.e. it doesn't come from a third-party plugin.)

Comment: @BjørnVester Unfortunately it comes from a third-party plugin. The [openapi](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin) plugin to be more precise.


It is defined here  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/266de25cf3728ec1e21b7382366a021874037851/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/openapitools/generator/gradle/plugin/tasks/GenerateTask.kt#L76-L81